# Use schema.rb in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'd like `rake db:schema:load` to use a `db/schema.rb` that's not located in my app, but in one of my gems. This already works for `db:seed` by putting `config.paths['db/seeds'] = Core::Engine.paths['db/seeds'].existent` in my `application.rb`. (Core is a gem that's also a Rails engine).

However, there is no `db/schema.rb` path in `config.paths` and `config.paths['db'] = Core::Engine.paths['db'].existent` has no effect.

What's the easiest way to get this done?

Comment: Because I have 4 applications that all use the same models, and I want  all apps to have the same schema and migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Rails 3.2 source code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L400 , setting SCHEMA env variable should help:

```
ENV['SCHEMA'] = Core::Engine.paths['db'].existent
```

As I remember, the database tasks has been changed significantly in Rails 4, so this approach doesn't necessarily work in Rails 4.

Another option is to override the rake task itself in your gem.

Comment: This works, thanks! I used `ENV['SCHEMA'] = Core::Engine.paths['db'].existent.first + "/schema.rb"`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, as of Rails 4.0 you can set the 'db' key in your engine configuration and the main app will look for your schema there.

[active_record/railties/databases.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L238)

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer :override_db_dir do |app|
      app.config.paths["db"] = config.paths['db'].expanded
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get migrations from your gem - rake gem_name:install:migrations

Comment: I didn't know that, but that's not quite what I wanted, I want the schema.rb from the gem.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a custom rake task ?

```
desc 'Load a custom.rb file into the database'
  task :load_default_schema do
    file = ENV['SCHEMA'] || "path_to_your_file"
    if File.exists?(file)
      load(file)
    else
      abort %{#{file} doesn't exist yet.}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

While not totally the same thing you can do the following to have migrations in a gem act like they are part of the application. Which I have found to be a more elegant solutions for my purposes instead of trying to share schema. I hope this helps.

[Migrations in Rails Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526122/migrations-in-rails-engine/11213345#11213345)