# Rails gem developement coping resources to the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, copy-paste, database-migration

In my gem (myEngine.rb) I have the following code :

```
require "myEngine/version"
require "myEngine/models/contact"
require 'rails/generators'
module myEngine


 def self.generate_migration

  file_name= "migrationSrc.rb"
  src_path= "myEngine/migration_files/"+file_name
  destination_path=  "db/migrate/"+file_name
  //
  end
end
```

When I call the method generate_migration I want my gem to copy the migration file to the db/migrate of my application.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3

Comment: I have a problem with the copy_file method. It seems that it's not defined

Comment: maybe this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526122/migrations-in-rails-engine

Comment: @NabilaDevelopper That's because it must be called from inside a class that inherits from `Rails::Generators::Base`.

Comment: Yes I did that. I am on rails 4