# is it possible to add migration for rails app to ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For my rails project I want to write a ruby gem which have an ActiveRecord model eg. `Animal < ActiveRecord::Base`. Is it possible to add migration cretae_animals to the gem in such a way that when the gem installed in my app and I run `rake db:migrate` that migration will execute?

Comment: You could add a generator to your gem that creates needed migrations. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4725949/2483313

Comment: Yes I know, Im looking for a way when I can run all migrations with a single command

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by including the migrations with your gem, as well as including a rake task that runs them. Then you call the rake task as follows:

```
myGem = Gem::Specification.find_by_name 'gem-name'
load "#{myGem.gem_dir}/lib/tasks/my_migration.rake"
```

(Proper credit to Andy Atkinson, where I [originally learned this](http://andyatkinson.com/blog/2014/06/23/sharing-rake-tasks-in-gems) for a similar project.)